# The time is wrong in MySQL "data/*.err" file

Tags: mysql, timezone

I use "select now();" in MySQL client, the return time is right, is my system time. But the time in the "data/g1.err" is wrong, the "g1" is my computer name. The time's minute is right, so I think this is the problem of timezone. How can I correct the time in the error log time?

Comment: What OS?  What do you get from `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%zone%';`?

Comment: mysql> show variables like '%zone%';  
    +------------------+---------------------+  
    | Variable_name    | Value               |  
    +------------------+---------------------+  
    | system_time_zone | China Standard Time |  
    | time_zone        | SYSTEM              |  
    +------------------+---------------------+  
    My OS is Windows 10 Pro.